# React: Anonymous export default vs. Named export default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there any performance hit, undesired side effects or preferred standard when exporting an anonymous React component versus a named component?

**anonymous component export**

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>;
```

**named component export**

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>;

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: That is not even a named export, it's just a default export of a value stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Named exports are only truly necessary when you are doing non-default exports.

I disagree with the above.

With IntelliSense and/or TypeScript `export default MyComponent` is preferable because it tells Intellisense and TypeScript more and allows you to automatically import your module using extensions in your IDE. If there is no performance hit then the named export is the superior syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance hit, but naming allows for better readability and functionality with your editor

Answer (score 1):

If you write "export default () => { ... }" to declare components, they:

- will show up as Anonymous in stack traces
- will show up as Unknown in DevTools
- won't be checked by React-specific lint rules
- won't work with some features like Fast Refresh

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1255229440860262400

Answer (score -2):

There are no performance hits as the default export is actually named during import, i.e.:  `import MyFancyNamedComponent from './MyComponent'`

Named exports are only truly necessary when you are doing non-default exports.